# New facebook payment flow "App not allowed to use new flow."

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, payment

I've been attempting to implement the new facebook payment flow for local currency as per their documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/)

Have the company set up, have the product set up, have the payment FB.ui call set up, have the payments callback set up as required for it.

The issue I have is as soon as I call the FB.ui method to invoke a pay dialogue I get the error "Your Action Could Not Be Processed" on screen. Then once I hit ok my javascript callback gets the error message "App not allowed to use new flow." error code "1383005". I can't seem to find any help about this error message or error code (the error code is listed as "PermissionDenied - Facebook system issue" in the Error codes section). My question is am I missing something? There is nothing I can see in the docs that tells me how to allow my app to use the new flow or even telling me that I have to.

My payment dialogue code just in case:

```
var purchaseProduct = function (productUrl, callback) {
    var obj = {
        method: 'pay',
        action: 'purchaseitem',
        product: productUrl            
    };
    FB.ui(obj, function(response) {
        callback(response);
    });
};
```

(The quantity and request_id parameters are optional)

Thanks

Comment: Getting the same error. It seems that the new flow has just not yet been enabled for common use. The new flow pages do clearly state

`"This document describes a technology that is still in its final design phase and is subject to change."`

I'd guess that we won't be able to use it until this final design stage has been passed... Would be happy to be proven wrong, though ;)

Comment: To be fair I'm hoping its literally that they haven't put it out for common use yet. Yeah I saw that, but then in the "Getting Started" part it says "Developers can start integrating with Local Currency Payments right away. Read the API documentation to find more technical details." .. Bit of a contradiction. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: `"We are transitioning all canvas game developers away from Facebook Credits to local currency payments by September 12, 2013, 90 days after breaking change announcement."` So, from June 12th on, we should be able to use it, anyway...

Comment: As of a developer RSS feed from Wednesday 5th June 2013 at 7:15pm:
"Today we are launching the local currency payments API for all game developers to integrate into their current and future apps. Per our breaking change policy, we are giving developers 90 days to migrate to local currency payments. After September 12, 2013, we will no longer be able to support Facebook Credits. In order to continue accepting payments, please plan to migrate your app before that date." ... looks like it might be sorted, haven't tested yet though